# In php, how can I use a regular expression to capture everything between two patterns (and the shortest instance of each pattern)?

Tags: php, regex

I must be overcomplicating this, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I have a standard html document stored as a string, and I need to get the contents of the paragraph.
I'll make an example case.

```
$stringHTML=
"<html>

<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second</p>
<p>This is the third</p>
<p>And fourth</p>

</body>
</html>";
```

If I use

```
$regex='~(<p>)(.*)(</p>)~i';
preg_match_all($regex, $stringHTML, $newVariable);
```

I won't get 4 results. Rather, I'll get 10. I get 10 because the regex matches the first `<p>` and first `</p>` as well as the first `<p>` and fourth `</p>`

How can I search between two words, and return only the results of whats between each paragraph?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use a DOM parser.

Comment: I know, and thanks for the tip but this is actually just for regex practice, so if it comes up in other situations, I'll be up to the job.

Comment: I suggest you find something more useful to practice on, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.*?` to get the shortest match instead of the longest match.

Comment: And this will yield 4 results?

Comment: Why don't you "give it a go"!

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(34) "

This is the first paragraph
" [1]=> string(25) "

This is the second
" [2]=> string(24) "

This is the third
" [3]=> string(17) "

And fourth
" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "

" [1]=> string(3) "

" [2]=> string(3) "

" [3]=> string(3) "

" } [2]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(27) "This is the first paragraph" [1]=> string(18) "This is the second" [2]=> string(17) "This is the third" [3]=> string(10) "And fourth" } [3]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "
" [1]=> string(4) "

" [2]=> string(4) "

" [3]=> string(4) "

" } }

Comment: ... Not what I wanted, but still easier to chop up.

Comment: You seem to be printing it out as HTML, so you're not seeing the tags that were matched by `(<p>)` and `(</p>)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML parser  like DOM or XPATH to parse HTML. [**Dont use Regex to parse HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Here is how it can be easily parsed by DOMDocument.

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($stringHTML);
$ps = $doc->getElementsByTagName("p");
for($i=0;$i<$ps->length; $i++){
    echo $ps->item($i)->textContent. "\n";
}
```

[**Code in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GBXxsm)

---

Using this RegEx (as you said *its a regex practice*) you'll get 4 results.

```
preg_match_all("#<p>(.*)</p>#", $stringHTML, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Here [look around syntaxes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are  used. See [**the code in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DTUptJ).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be `/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i` . It will only matches the strings between `<p></p>` and put it in an array.

*you shouldn't do a group : `(<p>)`*